# Python class - how to update variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need some advice/ help with a question I'm currently doing for practice at my school.

We're using a Student Class and one of the methods is called `apply_marks(self,practical, theory)` and we must assume that the two inputs given are a number from 1-100, so we must update them.

The code I wrote:

```
def set_marks(self, practical, theory):

        self.practical = practical
        self.theory = theory
        i = 0
        if i in range(0,101):
            self.practical += i 
            self.theory += i
        return self.practical, self.theory
```

Any help would be great. Sorry if I haven't been clear or given enough information, please let me know :) !

Comment: Why did you write the loop? What is the method `set_marks` supposed to do?

Comment: You must check two inputs are in `range(0,101)`?

Comment: You might be better off posting this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Simple `if` statements seems like the proper solution:

```
if 0 <= practical <= 100:
    self.practical = practical
else:
    print("practical marks out of range: ", practical)

if 0 <= theory <= 100:
    self.theory = theory
else:
    print("theory marks out of range: ", theory)

# .. rest of code
```

A sequence is usually used for iteration or as a data structures. This is not a use case.

The code you have sets a variable to 0 and the makes sure the variable is in the range `[0, 101)`, which is always true. It then adds the variable value (0, which is ultimately a no-op) to both marks:

```
i = 0
# always true, you just set i to 0
if i in range(0,101):
    # this is a no-op, equivalent to self.practical = self.practical + 0
    self.practical += i
    # also a no-op
    self.theory += i
```

It doesn't make any sense with respect to your task or function signature.

Comment: the code you sent makes sense to me but for some reason I'm still not getting the output i want. the variables aren't being updated and still are at 0.

Comment: def set_marks(self, practical, theory):
       if 0 <= practical <= 100:
                self.practical = practical
            else:
                return practical 
            if 0 <= theory <= 100:
                self.theory = theory
            else:
                return theory